# Unexpected output when printing javascript array in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using the Chrome developer console:

```
a = [];
console.log(a); // returns [extend: function]
```

It's clear that the array is empty, as expected. What exactly is meant by the phrase 'extend: function'? Why is this printed instead of just '[]'?

Comment: I don't see that in the Chrome console - I just see `[]`

Comment: Opening a new tab, I'm also getting your result. I think it may have to do with the application running on the page..